# View Pager crashing on selected particular page in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am showing the view pager in android using **PagerAdpater**. It's worked well when I swipe the pages but when I selected a particular page by  **pager. setCurrentItem ()** method  after this my app crashed. after debugging the code we rectified that the pager add pet does not return the inflate view so we don't get it from XML file.

**This is my Pager Adapter**

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                resId = R.layout.scrollable_list;
                Log.i("name", "page3" + resId);
                break;
            }
            case 1: {

                    resId = R.layout.page0;

                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                resId = R.layout.page3;
                Log.i("name", "page3" + resId);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                Log.i("AFlow", "excuting");
                resId = R.layout.page4;
                Log.i("name", "page4" + resId);
                break;
            }
        }
        View view = (View) inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        collection.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**This is my Log Cat**

```
06-27 07:28:46.475 26166-26166/com.demol.viewpager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.demol.viewpager, PID: 26166
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.demol.viewpager.IntroductionFragment.addlist(IntroductionFragment.java:2429)
at com.demol.viewpager.IntroductionFragment.onCreateView(IntroductionFragment.java:163)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**After debugging I found this issue when I swipe the page list view return id but directly select page list view return null id I think this is the main problem**

Any help, suggestion, tutorials would be highly appreciated. Thank you....

Comment: Just post your crash log.. The above code looks fine.

Comment: In `instantiateItem()` use  `View view = (View) inflater.inflate(resId, collection,false);`

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/
Hope this helps

Comment: What is the line at IntroductionFragment.java:2429?

Comment: it is a list view s  inst_list.setAdapter(inst_adapter);